# Protect files on s3, only download file from link in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, fog

In my app, PDFs are generated with wicked_pdf and uploaded to Amazon S3 with the [fog](http://fog.io/) gem.

It works!

My current setup is to put the files in a folder generated by `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(40)`. Hard to guess. Security through obscurity. I then save the `public_url` in the database.

However, I would like to protect the files so that they can only be downloaded from links in the app. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Fog public credential to false, if you are using carrier wave then it's easy
`@report.report_attachment.url` one more way is

create controller action like this

```
def download_report
    @report = Report.find(params[:id])

    # url to access private files on S3 expire in 10 sec
    redirect_to @report.report_attachment.expiring_url(10)
  end
```

Comment: +1. Thank you, but I am not using Carrierwave. Is there any way to do a similar thing with only the fog library? I've set `:public => false`, and now I can't download the file at all (but it is uploaded). How can I create an expiring url in fog, and what do I save to the database (equivalent of public_url... or something for private files) so it can be downloaded again at a later date? Thanks!